# How to sign up for archive.org/download/project-name?

Tags: archive.org

How to sign up to have a link such as
`https://archive.org/download/project-name`?

example: https://archive.org/download/QubesOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the top right corner of the site

[image: How to upload files to achive.org]

As stated in the respective official pages:

**[About the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/about/)**

> Anyone with a free account can upload media to the Internet Archive. We work with thousands of partners globally to save copies of their work into special collections.

**[The Internet Archive Software Collection](https://archive.org/details/software?tab=about)**

> Finally, do not miss the [Open Source Software
>   Collection](https://archive.org/details/open_source_software), which
>   is the default contribution space for the users of the Internet
>   Archive to keep copies of software available to all. Tens of thousands
>   of programs, distributions and provisions are located here.   ....
>   Please contact Jason Scott, software curator at the Internet Archive,
>   with questions, suggestions or possible donations to the collection.